# Fixing boundaries for bokeh zoom-in and zoom-out

Tags: python, bokeh

I am struggling with zooming-in and zooming-out of a bokeh candlestick graph. It goes too much into detail with the zoom-in, and I want it to stop somewhere with at least 5-7 bars when zooming-in (depending on the position of the cursor), and go back to the original graph when zooming-out (regardless of the position of the cursor, and return to the original graph).

I tried playing around with `match_aspect=True` and `bm.DataRange1d` and I still don't get how the those.

So far it zooms in up to milliseconds and zooms out very far and not according to the aspect ratio of the initial graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.models as bm
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:51]

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close

p = figure( tools='xpan, xwheel_zoom', active_scroll='xwheel_zoom', 
       plot_width=1000, plot_height=500,  title = "MSFT", x_range=bm.DataRange1d(bounds='auto'),
       active_drag='xpan')
# map dataframe indices to date strings and use as label overrides
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
i: date.strftime('%b %d') for i, date in 
p.xaxis.bounds = (0, df.index[-1])

p.segment(df.index, df.high, df.index, df.low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[inc], 0.5, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[dec], 0.5, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

show(p)
```

Ideally, I would like to get a zoom similar to the [tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ%3AAAPL)  website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataRange1d` ranges have [`min_interval`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.min_interval) and [`max_interval`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.max_interval) properties you can set to prevent the range from ever being zoomed in smaller or larger than that:

```
p.x_range.min_interval = 1
p.x_range.max_interval = 10
```

Comment: it solves my first problem perfectly, thanks! But there is still an issue with zooming-in and zooming-out, if you change cursor position while zooming, it does not go back to the original graph when zooming-out. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: There is a[`maintain_focus`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.WheelZoomTool.maintain_focus) property on the `WheelZoomTool` you could try setting to False. This is only going to be useful if you constrain the total bounds, but in that case it will allow the zoom to "glide" back to whatever maximum bounds there are. If the total bounds are not constrained then I think an explicit "reset" button that restores the bounds you want, is it the only option.

Comment: Could it be that this solution does not work for 'datashaded' (e.g. rasterize() ) or did some behaviour change since '19?

Comment: @mths your comment is too vague to speculate. Datashader is not a part of Bokeh, and Bokeh does not care about the glyph type (e.g. `Image` from Datashader) when maintaining focus. Please open an entirely new question with complete details (expecially a minimal reproducible example) specific to your problem.

Comment: "> too vague" - @bigreddot you're absolutely right. And it wasn't as transferable between technologies as I first assumed in my newbie attitude. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73151222/how-to-disable-infini-zoom-with-bokeh-holoviews)