# How to disable infini-zoom with bokeh/holoviews

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am having trouble limiting the min/max zoom level in bokeh using holoviews datashader.
A similar question (w/o the datashader tho) is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888296/fixing-boundaries-for-bokeh-zoom-in-and-zoom-out/56893122#comment129155006_56893122).

Groundworks (I just copied from my ipynb so apologies for the out-of-proper-order code):

```
import bokeh
import datashader as ds
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, shade, dynspread, spread, rasterize
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

As said and solved in the other SO thread, limiting zoom works fine w/o any datashader opereation.
When I create a custom mock dataframe (see `N`), bokeh alone won't -reasonably- work well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = int(10e6)
x_r = (0,100)
y_r = (100,2000)
z_r = (0,10e8)
x = np.random.randint(x_r[0]*1000,x_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
y = np.random.randint(y_r[0]*1000,y_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
z = np.random.randint(z_r[0]*1000,z_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
z2 = np.ones((N,1)).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x,y,z,z2]), columns=['x','y','z','z2'])
df[['x','y','z']] = df[['x','y','z']].div(1000, axis=0)
df
```

So I employ the help of holoviews datashader

```
# infini-zoom still possible with x_range as rasterize param
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
palette = get_cmap('viridis')
# palette_inv = palette.reversed()

p=hv.Points(df,['x','y'], ['z','z2'])
# Points of course doesnt have a x_range attr
# p.x_range.min_interval = 1
# p.x_range.max_interval = 10 

P=rasterize(p, aggregator=ds.sum("z2"),x_range=(0,100)).opts(cmap=palette)
P.opts(tools=["hover"]).opts(height=500, width=500,xlim=(0,100),ylim=(100,2000))
```

`rasterize` seems to ignore any x_range argument. But this leaves me with a plot where you can infinitely(?) zoom in our out. Which I want to limit. For now I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, grep'ed and read through the holoviews docs I think I got one solution.
The trick is to add hook and handles. Like so:

```
def plot_limits(plot, element):
             plot.handles['x_range'].min_interval = 1
             plot.handles['x_range'].max_interval = 100
             plot.handles['y_range'].min_interval = 20
             plot.handles['y_range'].max_interval = 2000
P.opts(hooks=[plot_limits])
```

I think I'll wait a little longer with accepting in case someone has a similar or better solution **and** some explanation. But the above works.